# Transistor impedance

Tags: transistors, rf, radio, impedance-matching

According to LDMOS transistor AFT05MS031N datasheet at p. 13 " ZSource - Test circuit impedance measured from gate to ground" for 155 MHz is
Z = 4.31 + j.7.54

https://www.nxp.com/products/radio-frequency/rf-mobile-radio/136-520-mhz-31-w-13-6-v-wideband-rf-power-ldmos-transistors:AFT05MS031N

It is not input transistor impedance as I understand - it is full matched source (not in 50 ohm system) or something else?
And then input impedance of this transistor at 155 MHz is Z = 4.31 - j.7.54?

And similary output impedance is 2.77 + j1.23
It is correct?

Thanks you.